# Why is $\psi_1 : Im(\psi) \to Im(\psi)$ a regular skew mapping, where $\psi$ is skew.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the [book](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) of *Linear Algebra* by Greub, at page 230, it is stated that

> More general, it will now be shown that the rank of a skew
>   transformation is always even. Since every skew mapping is normal (see
>   sec. S.5) the image space is the orthogonal complement of the kernel.
>   Consequently, the induced transformation $\psi_1 : Im(\psi) \to
>  Im(\psi)$ is regular. Since $\psi_1$ is again skew, it follows that
>   the dimension of $Im(\psi)$ must be even. It follows from this result
>   that the rank of a skew-symmetric matrix is always even.

Note: we are working on a finite real inner product space, and $\psi$ is any skew map, i.e $ \psi^* = - \psi$, where $\psi^*$ denotes the adjoint mapping.

My question is that why is $\psi_1 : Im(\psi) \to  Im(\psi)$ a regular skew mapping, where  $\psi$ is skew.I mean I do not see how is that possible because since $\psi$ is normal and skew mapping, it should map $Im \psi$ to $Ker \psi$, so I do not understand how there is a "induced" map with these (co)domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote the undelying inner product space by $V$ ( $\dim V < \infty$). Then

$V= Im ( \psi) \oplus ker ( \psi)$, hence

$Im( \psi)= Im(\psi^2)$. This shows that $\psi_1$ is surjective.

If $x \in ker( \psi_1)$ then $x \in Im ( \psi) \cap ker ( \psi)=\{0\}$ ,

thus $\psi_1$ is injective.

Comment: By the way, why is $Im( \psi)= Im(\psi^2)$ ?

Comment: $ Im ( \psi)= \psi(V)= \psi(Im ( \psi) \oplus ker ( \psi))$. Can you proceed ?